# Passing variable into actionFunction and then back to JS function oncomplete

Tags: apex, javascript, apexactionfunction

Can I pass a variable into an apex:actionFunction call as follows:

```
deleteThing(thing_id);

<apex:actionFunction name="deleteThing" action="{!deleteAttachment}" reRender="none"
                     oncomplete="remove_deleted_thing(thing_id)">
    <apex:param name="thingToDelete" value="" assignTo="{!selectedAttachmentId}" />  
</apex:actionFunction>


public String selectedAttachmentId {get; set;}

public PageReference deleteAttachment() {
    Attachment attachment = getSelectedAttachment();
    delete attachment;
    return null;
}

private Attachment getSelectedAttachment() {
    return [SELECT Id FROM Attachment WHERE Id= :selectedAttachmentId];
}

function remove_deleted_thing(thing_id) {
    console.log(thing_id);
}
```

So that after {!deleteAttachment} runs in my controller, thing_id will be passed to remove_deleted_thing()?

I'm not even getting 'undefined' in my console now, so I assume I'm doing somthing wrong here. The code does what it's supposed to do up until remove_deleted_thing.

Amy suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try putting `return false;` so the code would be `oncomplete="remove_deleted_thing(thing_id);return false;"`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion highfive but that didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure that your `action` method working fine without any exceptions?

Comment: Well no errors have popped up yet and it's deleting my records. You can see it's a very simple method. Since it's deleting the record, could the Id be deleted along with it? And therefore can't be passed on to the next function? Does that even make sense??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed my actionFunction to the following, and all is well :)

```
<apex:actionFunction name="deleteThing" action="{!deleteAttachment}" reRender="none" 
                 oncomplete="remove_deleted_thing('{!selectedAttachmentId}') <-- HERES THE CHANGE">
    <apex:param name="thingToDelete" value="" assignTo="{!selectedAttachmentId}" />  
</apex:actionFunction>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a "hack" that could potentially be broken by Salesforce updates you can also write:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="deleteThing" action="{!deleteAttachment}" reRender="none" 
  oncomplete="remove_deleted_thing(request.options.parameters.thingToDelete)">
<apex:param name="thingToDelete" value="" assignTo="{!selectedAttachmentId}" />
```

The onComplete method of the action function in Visualforce appears like this when it's compiled down to JS:

```
function(request,event,data) {
  remove_deleted_thing(request.options.parameters.thingToDelete);
}
```